# Passing main arguments after subparser arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Imagine you've got common arguments for several subparsers:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
        "--learn_rate",
        type=float,
)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='task', dest='lib')
spacy_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        "spacy",
)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

From the command line, you have to run `python test.py --learn_rate 2 spacy`. Is it possible to make it so that `python test.py spacy --learn_rate 2` also works?

Comment: Arguments are parsed in the order they are given.  Once the main encounters the subparser's cmd, it passes all the remaining `argv` to the subparser.  You could define a '--learn_rate' argument for both main and sub, though I'd recommend giving them different `dest` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`learn_rate` isn't an option common to your subparsers; it's an option on the main command, which is available to your code regardless of which subparser gets invoked. If you truly want to share an option among multiple subparsers as in your second use case, you need to define it in a parent parser.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

shared_parent = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
shared_parent.add_argument(
        "--learn_rate",
        type=float,
    )

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='task', dest='lib')
spacy_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        "spacy",
        parents=[shared_parent]
)

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

---

Allowing `--learn_rate` to be used in *either* position is trickier. While you could define the `shared_parent` parser first, then add it to the main parser as well with `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[shared_parent])`, the subcommand will overwrite whatever value you specify from the main parser with the default if you don't use the option from the subparser. Working around this behavior of `argparse` would probably require a custom action at the very least.

Comment: Using a shared parent like in your example does not include arguments that are unspecified in the command line but have a default in the resulting `args` dict.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    )
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='task', dest='lib')
    spacy_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        "spacy",
        help="Spacy's Textcat",
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    )
    ulmfit_parser = subparsers.add_parser(
        "ulmfit",
        help="Fastai's ULMFiT",
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    )

    for subparser in subparsers.choices.values():
        subparser.add_argument(...)
```

Comment: or you could have collected references to the subparsers in your own list.  Loops and utility functions are useful tools when creating multiple similar subparsers or arguments.